# How to access docker container from another machine on local network

Tags: networking, docker

I'm using Docker for Windows( I am not using Docker Toolbox that use a VM) but I cannot see my container from another machine on local network. In my host everything is perfect and runs well,however, I want that other people use my container.

Despite being posting the [same question in Docker's Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-access-docker-container-from-another-machine-on-local-network/4737) , The answer was not show it. Plus, I have been looking for here but  the solutions found it are about setting up the bridge option in the virtual machine , and as I said before, I am using Docker for windows that no use Virtual machine.

Docker version Command

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
789d7bf48025        gogs/gogs           "docker/start.sh /bin"   5 days ago          Up 42 minutes       0.0.0.0:10022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5656->3000/tcp   gogs
7fa7978996b8        mysql:5.7.14        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   5 days ago          Up 56 minutes       0.0.0.0:8989->3306/tcp                          mysql
```

The container I want to use is gogs that is working in the port 5656.

When I use localhost:5656 y  127.0.0.1:5656  work properly, but when I use My local network IP (192.168.0.127) from other machine  the container is unreachable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Docker for Windows still uses a virtual machine (a Hyper-V virtual machine). Perhaps this would help http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2015/11/hyper-v-virtual-switch-using-nat-configuration/

Comment: @techraf yes the firewall is unable. 3306 is from  the container  of mysql but i am mapping this to 8989. What do you mean with the visivility of 3309 maybe you wanted to say if i can access to 3000 port from other network. if so, I cannot access to 3000 either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution:

When I installed Docker for Windows, it creates a network called **vEthernet (DockerNAT)** (Usually with the ip 10.0.75.1)

My local machine had a network called **local area connection** with the ip 192.168.0.172(With this ip I was trying to access from other PCs).

So far, My local Machine had Two networks Conections so that  I went to  **Control panel** > **NetWork and Sharing center** > **Change Adapter Settings**  I selected the two networks and I right-click selected **Add to bridge**. That create a Third network called **Ethernet**.

At this point, I didnt know what was the Ip of **Ethernet** network, so I executed ipconfig command that show me the ip 192.168.0.17(The settings of **local area connection** and **vEthernet (DockerNAT)** disappeared and the ips 10.0.75.1 and 192.168.0.172 stop working).

With this new ip (192.168.0.17) I tried from other machine in the network and finally I could access to the container(192.168.0.17:5656).

Answer (score 2):

In Hyper-V settings, putting "Docker NAT" network in "external" mode worked for me. (I can access to my container on my local network with my host's IP)